# WCF with NTLM over HTTPS and Certificates for the Message?

Tags: .net, wcf, x509certificate, ntlm

I want to setup a WCF Service that uses NTLM Authentication over HTTPS and uses Certificate security for the message (I know, usually HTTPS negates the need for message encryption)

I have the Certificates working over message security, but when I try to use TransportWithMessageCredential, the client throws an exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'

IIS is configured to only support Windows Auth, Require SSL and Accept Client Certificates, machines are in the same Active Directory Domain (in fact, i'm running this locally right now)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

My Service web.config looks like this:

```
<services>
    <service name="ServiceHost.MyTestService" behaviorConfiguration="CertificateServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="ws2007HttpBinding" contract="SharedLibrary.ITestService" bindingConfiguration="CertificateBindingConfig">
        </endpoint>
    </service>
</services>

<bindings>
    <ws2007HttpBinding>
        <binding name="CertificateBindingConfig">
            <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </ws2007HttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CertificateServiceBehavior">
            <serviceCredentials>
                <windowsAuthentication allowAnonymousLogons="false" />
                <clientCertificate>
                    <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" />
                </clientCertificate>
                <serviceCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="server" />
            </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

My Clients app.config is this:

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="https://server:9999/ServiceHost/TestService.svc" binding="ws2007HttpBinding"
                contract="SharedLibrary.ITestService" bindingConfiguration="CertificateBindingConfig" 
                behaviorConfiguration="CertificateEndpointBehavior"
                name="serviceEndpoint">

    </endpoint>
</client>
<bindings>
    <ws2007HttpBinding>
        <binding name="CertificateBindingConfig">
            <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="true"/>
            </security>
        </binding>
    </ws2007HttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CertificateEndpointBehavior">
            <clientCredentials>
                <windows allowNtlm="true" allowedImpersonationLevel="Impersonation"/>
                <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="client"/>
                <serviceCertificate>
                    <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
                </serviceCertificate>
            </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: I assume your client cert is registered within the client's trusted certs?

Comment: @M.Babcock Yes, it's in the trusted people store. It works if I use Message security against an unauthenticated HTTP endpoint.

Comment: Do you use localhost in your endpoint address?

Comment: @GrzegorzWilczura Tried both localhost and my machine name

Comment: In the IIS Authentication settings for Windows Authentication. When you right click and choose Providers is it as simple as removing Negotiate from the list of providers? Anonymous authentication is Disabled as well in IIS?

Answer (score 1):

Predefined modes will not allow you achieving such security. `TransportWithMessageCredentials` means:

- HTTPS
- No transport authentications
- Security token in message for client authentication
- No message encryption

Try this (not tested) to get HTTPS with NTLM + mutual message security:

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="MegaSecurity">
      <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate"
                messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10"
                includeTimestamp="true" />
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10" />
      <httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Ntlm" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

You can also try `MutualSslNegotiated` authentication mode to have service credentials negotiation and `Negotiate` in `authenticationScheme` to better match `Windows` option from predefined bindings.